# Calculus limit with 2 variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How can i proof that the limit does not exist:

$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,1)} \frac{xy^2 - 1}{y-1}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the limit does not exist take two different pairs of sequences with limit $1$, and show that the limit in both cases is not equal.

If we approach $x$ and $y$ similar, we can set $x=y$ for starters. Then we get:
$$
\lim_{y\to 1} \frac{y^3-1}{y-1}=\lim_{y\to 1}(y^2+y+1)=3
$$

Setting $x=1$ however we get
$$
\lim_{y\to 1} \frac{y^2-1}{y-1}=\lim_{y\to 1}(y+1)=2
$$

So the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

Fix $x=1$ and take $y\to 1$ and you should get one limit. Now take $y=x$ and take the limit as $y\to 1$. Are they the same?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\Bbb R^n$ is first countable we can use the following theorem

> **Theorem**
>
> If $X$ is first countable and if $f:X\to Y$ is a function then $y_0$ is the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches at $x_0$ if and only if for any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converging to $x_0$ it happens that $\left(f(x_n)\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $y_0$.
>
> *Proof*. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739354/if-x-and-y-are-first-countable-then-lim-x-to-x-0fx-y-0-iff-lim-n-t).

So if we put $f(x,y):=\frac{xy^2-1}{y-1}$ then we consider the sequences $a_n:=\Big(\frac{1}n+1,\frac{1}n+1\Big)$ and $b_n:=\Big(\frac{1}{n^3}+1,\frac{1}n+1\Big)$ converging to $(1,1)$ and we observe that

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(a_n)=3\neq2=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(b_n)
$$
so that your statement follows directely form the above theorem.